# How to use Dropdown in bootstrap table header?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a bootstrap table.
and I want to use dropdown in table header.
so how to use dropdown in  tag.

Comment: Have you tried searching for the solution first? I see an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27902229/4252369)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Column 1
            </th>
            <th>
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="1">3</option>
                </select>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                ssss
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                ssss
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                aaa
            </td>
            <td>
                ssss
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: But my <th> tag is like this

Comment: <th data-field="added_on" data-sortable="true" data-align="right" data-sortable="true">Order Date</th>

Comment: data-sortable="true" is duplicated.